# Using "weather" to mean "weather report"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Can I say "I missed the weather today" meaning "I missed the weather report today"?

Comment: Yes. Same as *I listened to **the news** [report] this morning on the radio.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. *Merriam-Webster* has [this entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20weather):

> **the weather**
>
> : a report or forecast about the weather
>    *Check **the weather** before you make plans.*